# Differential form or differential form field?

Tags: differential-forms

When discussing differential forms is it necessary to stick the word “field” on the end , such as “1-form field”, or “2-form field” in a similar fashion to vector and vector field? Or is, in the context of forms, the use of “field” redundant? Thanks.

Comment: I think "field" is redundant. A differential form is a particular type of tensor field, as I understand it. A differential form assigns an alternating $k$-tensor to each point on a manifold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hardly anybody uses the word “field” in this context. Already when you say **differential** form, it's clear that it must be a field, since in order for the concept of derivative to be interesting, the quantity in question must vary from point to point.

Comment: Hubbard and Hubbard in *Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, And Differential Forms*, and Frankel in *The Geometry of Physics* both refer to form fields.

Comment: @Peter4075: Fair enough, I've moderated my statement a little! :-)